# Using MIN, MAX, (SUM/COUNT) subquery in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have this FACT_TABLE [image: FACT_TABLE] :

The **STEP** has a unique **DURATION**, **FOLDER** has one or many **STEP** and the **PRCEDURE** has also many **FOLDER** .

I want to get this **RESULT**, using SQL PostgreSQL Query, which means get the minimum sum duration of folder, maximum sum duration of folder and the Average of all folders grouped by **PRCEDURE**
 [image: RESULT]

I tried to solve it using subquery : 
`SELECT PROCEDURE.NAME, min(DUR), MAX(DUR), (SUM(DUR)/COUNT(DISTINCT ID_FOLDER))
from
(SELECT ID_FOLDER, SUM (DURATION) as DUR from FACT_TABLE
group by ID_FOLDER) 
Inner join PROCEDURE on PROCEDURE.ID = FACT_TABLE.ID_PROCEDURE 
GROUP By PROCEDURE.NAME ;`

But it didn't work, Did i miss somthing ? What is wrong in this logic ?

Comment: How did it not work?  Provide sample data and results that illustrate the problem.

Comment: Well , i have a problem in the join function  it doesn't work like that i don't know why he can't know it . Also when i do **group by** in the subQuery, it's error in pgAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind your query should work.  There are some tweaks:

```
SELECT p.NAME, MIN(pf.DUR), MAX(pf.DUR), AVG(pf.DUR)
FROM (SELECT f.ID_PROCEDURE, f.ID_FOLDER, SUM(f.DURATION) as DUR
      FROM FACT_TABLE f
      GROUP BY f.ID_PROCEDURE, f.ID_FOLDER
     ) pf JOIN
     PROCEDURE p
     ON p.ID = pf.ID_PROCEDURE 
GROUP BY p.NAME;
```

Note:

- The inclusion of `ID_PROCEDURE` in the subquery, so it can be used for the join and the aggregation is correct.
- The definition of table aliases for all tables.
- The use of qualified column names to avoid ambiguity.
- The use of the simpler `AVG()` rather than the ratio of a `SUM()` to a `COUNT()`.